# How to convert array in a df cell to individual column names?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am not able to convert below DF:

```
 | A | B |     C   |     
 | 1 | 2 | t1,t2,t3|     
 | 1 | 3 | t4,t5   |     
 | 2 | 2 | t1,t5   |
```

to below DF:

```
| A | B | t1 | t2 | t3 | t4 | t5 | 
| 1 | 2 | 1  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 
| 1 | 3 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 
| 2 | 2 | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 1  |
```

in scala spark.

Values in column `C` are comma separated and I want it to make them into separate columns. Once that is done I want to mark 0 and 1 in that particular row if `t1`, `t2`, etc. exists or not.

Please help here. Would really appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by using [`pivot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/RelationalGroupedDataset.html#pivot-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-). However, first split the the data on "," and [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) the `C` column.

```
df.withColumn("C", explode(split($"C", ",")))
  .groupBy("A", "B")
  .pivot("C")
  .count()
  .na.fill(0)
```

Result:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B| t1| t2| t3| t4| t5|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  2|  2|  1|  0|  0|  0|  1|
|  1|  2|  1|  1|  1|  0|  0|
|  1|  3|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

---

The above solution assumes that all rows have unique combinations of values in `A` and `B` (due to the use of `groupBy`). If this is not the case an additional step is necessary:

Add a new column with a unique id that can be used together with `A` and `B` in the `groupBy`, e.g.:

```
df.withColumn("D", monotonically_increasing_id)
```

This column can be deleted after the `pivot`.

Comment: you suppose here that A and B are unique which is may be not true

Comment: @firsni: You are correct, I overlooked that fact. I added some more information how to get around that issue.

Comment: count will not result into 0 or 1.

Comment: @SomilAseeja: If you get values > 1 then the A & B columns are not unique as firsni mentioned in the comment above. Add the `D` column as in the last part of the answer, then change the `groupBy` to `.groupBy("A", "B", "D")`. This should give you only 0 or 1 in each t column.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get all values from column `C` and then create a Set of that columns `C` as value which will use as columns name, check below process

1. Create Data Frame:

   ```
   val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((1, 2, "t1,t2,t3"), (1, 3, "t4,t5"), (2,2,"t1,t5"))).toDF("A","B","C")
   +---+---+--------+
   |  A|  B|       C|
   +---+---+--------+
   |  1|  2|t1,t2,t3|
   |  1|  3|   t4,t5|
   |  2|  2|   t1,t5|
   +---+---+--------+
   ```
2. Read Column value which require for header for Data frame :

   ```
   val cols = df.select($"C")
   val colnameAsHeader = cols.map(x=>x.getString(0).split(",")).collect.flatten.toSet
   ```
3. Create UDF for check criteria:

   ```
   def checkCriteria(inputString: String) = {udf((inputColumn: String) => { if(inputColumn.split(",").contains(inputString)){1}else{0} })}
   ```
4. Use foldLeft to set header :

   ```
   colnameAsHeader.foldLeft(df)((df, name) => df.withColumn(name , lit(checkCriteria(name)($"C")))).drop("C").show

   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   |  A|  B| t4| t5| t3| t2| t1|
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   |  1|  2|  0|  0|  1|  1|  1|
   |  1|  3|  1|  1|  0|  0|  0|
   |  2|  2|  0|  1|  0|  0|  1|
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible is to make use of spark sql functions of Spark 2.4 instead of udf asthe following:

Collect all values in values List then test foreach value in your list if it exists in your array column by using the array_contains method

```
val df1  = Seq(
  ("1", Array("t1", "t2")),
  ("2", Array("t1", "t3", "t5"))
).toDF("id", "arr")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit, array_contains, when}
val values = df1.select("arr").collect().map(x => x.getList[Array[String]](0).toArray)
  .flatMap(x => x)
  .distinct
  .map(_.toString)
val df2 = df1
  .select(df1.columns.map(col(_)) ++
    values.map(x => when(array_contains(col("arr"), x), 1).otherwise(0).alias(x)):_*)
df2.show()

+---+------------+---+---+---+---+
| id|         arr| t1| t2| t3| t5|
+---+------------+---+---+---+---+
|  1|    [t1, t2]|  1|  1|  0|  0|
|  2|[t1, t3, t5]|  1|  0|  1|  1|
+---+------------+---+---+---+---+
```